# How in blade template show params in maintenance-mode?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to add maintenance-mode support for my Laravel 5.7 app as written here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#maintenance-mode

with command in console :

```
php artisan down --message="Upgrading Database" --retry=60
```

using template

```
resources/views/errors/503.blade.php.
```

it works, but if there is a way in my console to show values of message and retry params entered in console command?

I tried to show variables with these names, but got error that such variables do not exists...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `message` and `retry` values in your blade view like this:

**Message:**

```
{{ $exception->getMessage() }}
```

**Retry:**

```
{{ $exception->retryAfter }}
```